# RxTextView in Kotlin cannot extract String from KFunction1

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-binding

In Java I use RxTextView and call .subscribe() in Fragment to invoke and transmit String as a parameter to a method in Presenter.
Everything works fine.

Java:

```
        compositeDisposable.add(
                RxTextView.textChanges(searchEditText)
                        .map(CharSequence::toString)
                        .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .distinctUntilChanged()
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                        .subscribe(query -> {
                            presenter.setQueryFilter(query); // query parameter: String
                        })
        );
```

I get confused with RxTextView in Kotlin because in function .subscribe( ... ) value parameter is a generic variance instead of a String only as in Java is.

**Kotlin:**

```
    compositeDisposable.add(
            RxTextView.textChanges(activity.findViewById(R.id.searchEditText))
                    .map {CharSequence::toString}
                    .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .distinctUntilChanged()
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                    .subscribe { query ->
                        getPresenter().setQueryFilter(query.toString()) //query parameter: KFunction1<CharSequence,String>! 
                        //query.toString gives a such result: fun kotlin.Any.toString(): kotlin.String
                    }
    )
```

**How could I get a proper string value from EditText and connect this with .subscibre() like in Java?**

**SOLUTION**

I replaced .map{CharSequence::toString} with: .map{**it.toString()**}

Comment: I tried your code and it gives me a string object in onNext

Comment: @tompee Do you have any idea how to extract proper input String in .subscribe{} function?

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: I resolved it by changing: map {CharSequence::toString} to map {it.toString()}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
map {CharSequence::toString}
```

to

```
map (CharSequence::toString)
```

Comment: I didn't recognize that there is a bracket and brace. When I rewrite it form Java to Kotlin I didn't see that it refactor to brace. Your answer is also correct, thanks!